# Importing and exporting data from SQL Server via sqoop with fields containing various text

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, db2, hdfs, sqoop

I'm trying to import and the export tables from SQL Server to DB2 via HDFS/Sqoop.

I'm using

```
--fields-terminated-by '\001' 
--lines-terminated-by '\002' 
--hive-replace-delims '<hivedelims>' 
and/or --hive-drop-import-delims
```

I can almost get everything done, but.....

Some columns in SQL Server are of type `nvarchar(max)` and contain data in the form of text like

```
"...[CR][LF] ..."
```

or XML-text containing the pipe-character: '|'

or simple text containing either \n or [LF] or [CR].... etc. etc.

Apparently the column can hold any kind of text....

I would like to import those kind of cells as one chunk into HDFS and export them likewise as one chunk into DB2...

I'm importing by using import-all-tables instead of one-by-one, otherwise I've thought of using --map-column-java for those specific tables/columns..?

However any combination I've tried leaves me with a few tables not able to export, as they are interpreted with different number of columns, due to above mentioned.

I hope it makes sense, otherwise I'm more than willing to elaborate with some actual data (anonymised, as they contains sensitive data)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it finally with the following:

In the sqoop import-all-tables section:

```
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n' \
```

In the sqoop export section:

```
--input-fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
```

That took care of everything.

Now I ran out of memory, but that's a completely other story ;-)

Hope it can be helpful for others.